# TabView after Login not updating view in IONIC 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using IONIC 2 + Angular 2.

I am using Tabview for my dashboard. The issue is when I try to redirect page with `this.nav.push(TabPage)`, A constructor of TabPage is getting called but View is not updating.

When I Minimise and Maximise app again, then I can see TabPage with all the Tabs but not without.

A problem is Tabs layout I guess as Its working if I redirect it to normal page instead of Tabs page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably ran into one of the many navigation/tabs [issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12625#issuecomment-325116785) which a present in the current version of ionic. You can try downgrading to ionic-angular version 3.5.3 which was the version before most of these issues were introduced by refactoring the way the NavController generates URLs.

Comment: I am using ionic-angular 2.0.0-beta-11 and tabs 0.2.0

Comment: Oh well thats a very old version, I guess there also were many bugs in the beta. You could try to manually run Angular change-detection via ChangeDetectorRef (https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to rule out its just an issue with that.